# Powered off when partitioning, can not run system recovery to back to out-of-box, factory state

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, laptop-repair

I was trying to run the built-in system recovery software to get the OS system back to the out-of-box, factory state for my TOSHIBA SATELLITE L510. The power was accidently off when the software try to partition the harddisk. I try the rerun the recovery software and Windows installation disk. Both of them could not find the partition of the harddisk. Anyone knows how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: If you made (full) recovery CDs or DVDs of the recovery partition, then the safest route is to use a utility to zero out the first track of the drive (WD and Seagate have utility CDs), then install the recovery partition and let it rebuild the drive.  There may be a better/faster solution, but first you'll have to provide a lot more detail as to what you have tried and what responses you saw.

Comment: Another reason to have the battery installed and fully charged when recovering.

Comment: Even better is to have battery installed and the AC adapter plugged in when recovering.

Comment: As I don't have recovery CDs or DVDs, I have to find another way. Ming

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install Windows XP but could not find the partition. I then tried to install Windows 7 and could see the partition!

After installing Windows 7, I could run the built-in recovery software to recover the built in OS again.

Comment: Smells like SATA AHCI - Windows XP needs drivers from floppy for that.